# How to get char from regular expression matching list

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to get all the characters from regular expression matching list with SQL ORACLE
Example: regular expression matching list is : `'[a-c2-5]'`

Result is table include rows:

```
a
b
c
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: What if your expression were `a*`? Would you want to return infinite records? Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you show more detail about which rows you would want to match and which ones you would not want to match, then you might make better progress.

Comment: @Welbog - I edited the post to reflect what I believe the OP meant. He is not thinking about match patterns in general, but rather, a "matching list" as defined in the context of regular expressions. The question makes sense (even though it is a bit odd).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like an XY problem (google the phrase to learn what it means). What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve this way?

In any case - here is one way to solve this. I assume you are only interested in ASCII characters (with ASCII codes between 1 and 255); you may generalize this if needed.

```
select     chr(level) as matched_character
from       dual
where      regexp_like(chr(level), '[a-c2-5]')
connect by level <= 255
;


MATCHED_CHARACTER
-----------------
2
3
4
5
a
b
c
```

Comment: I need solution for regular expression more and more
Example : [A-Z0-9]{2}
Result:
AA
AB
AC
AD
....
ZZ

And thanks for your answer

Comment: Exactly, I need listed all item between 'JPT6034' and 'JPT60JR' with SQL Oracle
Result : 204 item

Thanks and best regard!

Comment: @ThânQuangLong - Sorry, then I misunderstood your question. What you are asking now doesn't make any sense. Example: `A+`. What do you want the output to be? It is an infinite set! The problem I solved for you makes sense (but is more limited); the general problem doesn't.